# Change div layout with CSS? (Alternating divs)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am writing a plugin for WordPress. The layout is as following, displayed in a horizontal row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="information">
</div>
```

The PHP-function alternates the divs so every other row is the opposite order, like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="information">
    <div class="thumbnail">
</div>
```

This is all working out in a fullscreen page, but on smaller screen I would like to get the "row" displayed vertically non-alternating.

So I'd like to get the thumbnail displayed first, then the information for every row.

When adding the @media statements for the div to pop down, I get the wrong order due to the alternating divs like so:

1st thumbnail 
1st information 
2nd information 
2nd thumbnail

So I wonder if it's even possible to change through CSS? Been trying a lot of different floats and n-th childs but I end up with the same results.

Here is a jsbin to show the layout I am using: 
[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/coyecawaye/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order`  with  a mediaquery or with a `min-width` to set a break point .

```css
.row {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.information {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5%;
  min-width:250px;/* set a breakpoint at 500px where thumb is set at 50% */
}

.thumbnail {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 50%;/* min-width will allow to spray on the whole line when alone */
  background: teal;  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
.row:nth-child(odd) .thumbnail {
  order:1;
}
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="thumbnail">thumb</div>
    <div class="information">information goes here</div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="information">information goes here</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">thumb</div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="thumbnail">thumb</div>
    <div class="information">information goes here</div>
  </div>
```

min-width + order http://jsbin.com/xupurikuxu/1/edit?html,css,output

mediaquerie http://jsbin.com/senobugubi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Hey this is a great fix, but I'm having the same issue and cannot use flexbox. Any ideas? Also, should I post this as a new question or would that be a duplicate? I have an example of my issue here, you can see the floated content is not vertically aligned: http://codepen.io/benjibee/pen/mAxPGL

Comment: @Benji you may ask another question where you can provide your code and specify that flex is not to be used . From that code here, we could use direction and display:table /block to have a similar result i guess . example http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qaokLj

Comment: This is exactly the fix, it's perfect.Thank you! I've posted my question at this link, if you would be kind enough to answer it again for Googlers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39938950/401980