# Swapping columns (left / right) on alternate rows

Tags: html, css, layout, grid

I have a series of rows, each containing two columns, split 50/50 in width.

I'd like every other row to swap the left column (`.image`) to the right right, but I need to maintain the sequence in the HTML as it's displayed as one column on smaller screens.

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .image,
  .text {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50%;
      vertical-align: middle;
  }

  /* alternate */
  .row:nth-child(odd) .image {
    float: right;
  }

  /* clearfix */
  .row:before,
  .row:after {
      content: " ";
      display: table;
  }

  .row:after {
      clear: both;
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div><div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div><div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div><div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I know I can do this with flexbox, which I can't use in this project. And using `float: left` doesn't allow me to vertically align the elements. What other options do I have?

**NB:** I'm using `display: inline-block` for these columns, as they vary in height and I'd like them to be aligned vertically to one another.

**Edit:** I've [made a CodePen](http://codepen.io/benjibee/pen/xEWgoy) with the example using floats as shown above.

Comment: Please display your full code (including CSS)

Comment: I've updated it with CSS and a CodePen, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use `display:table`*(optionnal)*, `:nth-child(even)` and `direction` to swap div position :
[codepen](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VKXPAV)

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.row:nth-child(even) {
  direction: rtl;
}
.row:nth-child(odd) .image {
  text-align: right
}
.image,
.text {
  display: table-cell;
  direction: ltr;
  border: solid;
}
.text {
  background: tomato;
}
img {vertical-align:top;}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .row,
  .image,
  .text {
    display: block;
    direction:ltr
  }
  .row:nth-child(odd) .text {
  text-align: right
}
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="row">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. If you add `vertical-align: middle` to `.image, .text` it also centres the content vertically, which is what I wasn't able to do using the easiest fix: `float: right` – thanks for the clever solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
/* CSS */

.row .image {
   display: table-cell
}
.row .text {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: top;
}
.row:nth-child(even) .image {
   float: right;
}
.row {
   clear: both;
}
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EKfbzXs90ul4faDSI8tt)

Comment: Seems a good answer. But the OOP says that can't use float lef (I don't understand why) and you are using float right ...

Comment: Using floats wouldn't allow me to allow the columns vertically, i.e. with `vertical-align: middle` or such. You can see the issue in my updated post with the CSS and a CodePen. The answer I just accepted works around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you mean by "aligned vertically to one another". How exactly aligned?

But maybe you want to align them vertically using `vertical-align: middle` and then, yes, `float: left` is not your friend.

You say that your columns split 50/50 in width. Then you can use `position: relative` with `left: 50%;` and `right: 50%;` rules.

Like this:

```
.row {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.row > .image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #eef;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.row > .text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #fee;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.row:nth-child(even) > .image {
  left: 50%;
}
.row:nth-child(even) > .text {
  right: 50%;
}
```

The background color is just for demonstration.

This way each even row will swap columns and you can still use `vertical-align` rule. See the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lkcPLqsEYorgcyFH4ctW?p=preview).

Comment: I should've said "aligned middle" to allude to `vertical-align: middle` which is what I'm looking for. I've updated my original post with CSS and a CodePen.

Comment: @Benji, then I was able to guess what you want. :) Did you try my css or plunker? It works as you want. `position: relative` with left/right 50% offset do the trick. But @GCyrillus's solution using `direction` I like even more because it can be applied even on variable width elements.

Comment: Yes, I did, thank you! It does indeed do what I need, since I know the width. But I found @GCyrillus's solution so clever I went with it anyway :)